# How to style target="_blank" anchors?

Tags: css

I have been looking for a way to change the css of links all over my site that have a target:_blank;  Please note that I can only do this in css and not js.  Thank you.

Example:

```
<style>
a{ color : blue }
a:[target=_blank]{ color : green}
</style>

<a href="someplace.html">link1</a>
<a href="someplace.html" target="_blank">link2</a>
```

Link1 would be blue and Link2 would be green.

Comment: You forgot the quotes: `[target="_blank"]`

Comment: Yes you can do it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @Bluety it's the extra `:` made it not work

Comment: The `[target="blank"]` bit is an attribute selector, not a pseudo selector, so doesn't need the colon.

Comment: @Huangism oh yes I had not seen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/c0r6jzgf/)

```
a[target=_blank]{ color : green}
```

```css
a{ color : blue }
a[target=_blank]{ color : green}
```

```html
<a href="someplace.html">link1</a>
<a href="someplace.html" target="_blank">link2</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 provides attributes based classes which you can use to target them.

As in your case, you want to match the exact string, use

```
a[target="_blank"] {
  // styles here
  background: red;
}
```

Some similar variants:

```
a[href^="http:"] {
     // targets only links starting with http
}

img[src$=".png"] {
     // matches all images png images alone
}

a[href*="home"] {
       // matches all links which contains home in the link
}
```